# UIDocumentPickerModeExportToService does not show Drive or DropBox in iOS11

Tags: ios, ios11, uidocumentpickervc, uidocumentmenuvc, uidocumentbrowservc

I have been using UIDocumentMenuViewController and UIDocumentPickerViewController in my app to import images and pdfs from 3rd party apps like Google Drive, DropBox, iCloud etc. This is also used for exporting some pdfs from my app to these other apps. It was working fine until the latest iOS update.

In iOS 11, the import service works just as expected, but the place in my app where I try to export a pdf, the app just shows 'iCloud Drive' and 'On my iPhone' options. It does not show Google Drive or DropBox. This behavior is specific to iOS 11.

I read the documentation on Apple for UIDocumentMenuViewController, UIDocumentPickerViewController and UIDocumentBrowserViewController. None of them have specified any change for the 'UIDocumentPickerModeExportToService' mode in iOS11. Am I missing any update information from Apple?

Update: Dropbox and Google Drive released new versions of their apps compatible with iOS11. Updating these apps to the new version solves the issue!

Comment: Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox and Google Drive released new versions of their apps compatible with iOS11. Updating these apps to the new version solves the issue!